Unable to get LinkedIn API statistics - 500 response
I initially get a list of campaign_ids from the LinkedIn account
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

campaigns_url = f'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2?q=search&search.account.values[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:XYZ1234'

response = requests.get(campaigns_url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    campaigns_data = response.json()['elements']
else:
    print(f"Error fetching campaigns: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.json())
    campaigns_data = []

campaign_ids = [campaign['id'] for campaign in campaigns_data]
print(campaign_ids)

I retrieve the list of campaign_ids successfully. Then I want to retrieve the statistics of each sponsored campaign using the campaign ids through the following:
headers_2 = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}',
    'Linkedin-Version': '202409',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
}

base_statistics_url='https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics'
for campaign_id in campaign_ids:
    params = {
        'q': 'statistics',
        'pivots': 'List(CAMPAIGN,CREATIVE)',
        'dateRange': '(start:(year:2020,month:1,day:1)',
        'timeGranularity': 'YEARLY',
        'campaigns': f'List(urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:{campaign_id})'
    }
    ad_analytics_response = requests.get(base_statistics_url, headers=headers_2, params=params)
    print(ad_analytics_response.json()).

However, I get the following response from the server:
{'message': 'Internal Server Error', 'status': 500}


If the data you send over to a web API is faulty, it would typically result in a 400 error, not a 500 error. However, it's possible that the data you send is valid structurally, but still results in an error on the side of the server when processing the request.  From the API documentation, it seems that the issue may be with the value for 'campaigns', which has %3A instead of : for the URN value, i.e. f'List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A{campaign_id})'

It results in the same error
'campaigns': f'List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A{campaign_id})'

have you also tried encoding the date range? (excluding the parentheses)
